# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling_mean' [temp.append]

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
temp.append(pd.rolling_mean(pd.pivot_table(telemetry,
   index='datetime',
   columns='machineID',
   values=col), window=24).resample('3H',
        closed='left',
        label='right',
        how='first').unstack())
```

os:windows10
python3.7.1
conda 4.6.7

Comment: Including the exact error message you're getting would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

check it https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.0/whatsnew.html

```
FutureWarning: pd.rolling_mean is deprecated for DataFrame and will be removed in a future version, replace with
                       DataFrame.rolling(window=3,center=False).mean()
```

Comment: See also http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/whatsnew.html#window-functions-are-now-methods